# How to create a dictionary with data from a text file?

Tags: python-3.x

I have two columns in a text file like this:

```
William 2
David 3
Victor 5
Jack 1
Gavin 4
```

And I want it to be like this in a dict:

```
d = {'William': 2,'David': 3,'Victor': 5,'Jack': 1,'Gavin': 4}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I only have 3 days left to done this task!

Answer (score 0):

```
myDictionary = {}

with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        myDictionary[line.split()[0]] = int(line.split()[1])
```

You might want to read up more on [file i/o](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) and [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: @WilliamJi It's working fine for me. What do you mean by 'it goes five times'?

Comment: This needs a little change to get the desired output. `line.split()[1]` should be `int(line.split()[1]`. Anyway, why split twice?

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ Added `int`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
data = dict(line.split() for line in open('file.txt', 'r'));
```

Comment: `.readlines()` is not needed - `open()` already returns an iterator (and is lazy). Also, square brackets are not needed - there is no need to build huge list in memory when generator expression may be used as input argument to `dict`.

Comment: But it shouldn't have the top quote?!

Comment: When I run it this time it's like:   {'William': '2',...}

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as file:    
    for line in file.readlines():
        key, value = line.split()
        d[key] = int(value)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'David': 3, 'Gavin': 4, 'William': 2, 'Jack': 1, 'Victor': 5}
```